# How to use redshift regex to get out numbers in an array

Tags: amazon-redshift

In redshift, I have a column that contains an array-like string like [1,2,3] and I want to return `1,2,3` using Redshift's regex functionality. How can one do this? I don't want to do this:

```
SELECT LISTAGG(option_name , ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY option_name) as pets_names
    FROM reference.vital_options
    WHERE option_id in
        (
            -- this nested CTE splits the json string array into comma separated pet ids
            with NS AS (
                SELECT vo.option_id + 1 as n
                FROM <column with number id> as vo
                    WHERE upper(vo.country) = 'US'
                    ...
            )
            select TRIM(JSON_EXTRACT_ARRAY_ELEMENT_TEXT(u.pets_vital, NS.n - 1)) AS val
                FROM NS
                INNER JOIN go_prod.users AS u ON NS.n <= JSON_ARRAY_LENGTH(u.pets_vital)
            WHERE u.id = %(user_id)s
        )
    AND ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Is all you are trying to do is remove the square brackets?  If so then the translate() function is likely what you want to use.  For example:

```
create table test as (select '[1,2,3]'::text as A);

select a, translate(a, '][', '') as b from test;
```